# Why can't my bot kick users despite having admin perms and both intents enabled?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I made a kick command for my discord bot (hosted on repl.it). I enabled all of the intents and the bot has admin privileges, but still it raises an error
Code:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = Bot("$",help_command=None,intents=intents)
@bot.command()
async def k(ctx,member:discord.Member):
  await member.kick()
```

Error as text:

```
Ignoring exception in command k:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 91, in k
    await member.kick()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/member.py", line 568, in kick
    await self.guild.kick(self, reason=reason)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/guild.py", line 1997, in kick
    await self._state.http.kick(user.id, self.id, reason=reason)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 248, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

[image: the error image1]

**the error image**

I made a totally new bot and made the same kick command
but it still raises an exeption!

Comment: i still get the problem

Comment: Try to kick an user (for example one account of yours) with no roles. That should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Impossible...

...because the `Member` you tried to kick had an highest role higher than the `Bot` one.
For example, even if a Bot is an administrator, he can't kick the server owner.

---

Remember that a `discord.Bot` object is a way to interact with a discord Bot, which (using the API) can do the same things that a client would manage to do with the same permissions.
Try to kick the same `discord.Member` that your Bot tried to kick while having the same permissions: you won't be able to do it.

---

You should check the [`JSON Error Codes`](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/opcodes-and-status-codes#json-json-error-codes) of the [`Discord API`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html) when you don't understand what a `Discord.py` exception is caused by.

Comment: no the bot has the lowest possible privilages

Comment: hey this is my code https://replit.com/@devER-M/sockeyPy#main.py

Comment: The Bot must have the highest possible privileges and also its highest role must be the highest in the guild

Comment: so is this a bug in discord.py?

Comment: No, it's correct, the Bot must have a role higher than you to kick you. Otherwise a single bot could kick everybody from a server.

Comment: the bot is having admin and the other bot is having the lowest possible permissions 
so y can't the bot can't kick the other low permission bot? @FLAK-ZOSO

Comment: Try to use a discord.User which is not a Bot in this scope, to understand if the problem with kicking is only with bots.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238145/discussion-between-flak-zoso-and-dever-m).

Answer (score -1):

This is because you have not provided a valid reason!
Try this:

```
@bot.command()
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'User {member} has kicked.')
```

Hope it works!

Comment: No, that's not true. It depends on Permissions.

Comment: The bot has admin person and you can only kick with a reason!

Comment: Look at the error code, the error is raised because of "Missing Permissions", not because of a missing reason. (The reason is not compulsory anyway)

Comment: yes ur correct @FLAK-ZOSO